# Does Ring request {:scheme :https} guarantee a HTTPS connection?

Tags: ssl, https, clojure, ring

If the Ring request map key `:scheme` has value of `:https`, is it guaranteed that a HTTPS connection has been established and there were no certificate errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a question that relates to whatever servlet container you're using rather than ring.

ring-servlet populates the `:scheme` key by [getting a value from the HttpServletRequest](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/8927e9b3f556874720321078c85a62fcf9a23f1b/ring-servlet/src/ring/util/servlet.clj#L42):

`:scheme             (keyword (.getScheme request))`

The servlet specification has only this to say about `getScheme`:

> Returns the name of the scheme used to make this request, for example, http,
>   https, or ftp. Different schemes have different rules for constructing URLs,
>   as noted in RFC 1738.

Interestingly, ring-servlet **does not** call the `isSecure` method on the servlet request. So I think your question should probably be:

*"When using <insert your container name here> is it possible for getScheme() on a ServletRequest to return "https" when isSecure() returns false?"*

Comment: It can also get set based on the `X-forwarded-proto` header if you're running behind a reverse proxy using `ring-ssl` middleware, in which case all bets are off.

Comment: I have asked a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26148119/1714997) as per your suggestion.