# In Google App Engine is it possible for getScheme() on a ServletRequest to return "https" when isSecure() returns false?"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

In Google App Engine is it possible for getScheme() on a ServletRequest to return "https" when isSecure() returns false?"

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26140811/1714997).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is missing a little of the context you added on the other question, since your concern seems to be certificate errors I think an appropriate answer would be:

**Yes** getScheme() will return https even in the case of certificate errors, but only (of course) if the client opted to accept a server certificate that had errors (untrusted, expired, etc) during the SSL handshake. For instance, the client may have used the curl `-k` flag.

In your original question, you mentioned:

> *[if getScheme() returns "https"]* is it guaranteed that a HTTPS connection has been established and there were no certificate errors?

I think there's a flawed assumption in your question, that a certificate error means that an HTTPS connection is not established. In the case of certificate errors (untrusted issuer, expired certificate, etc), there are two possibilities:

1. The client terminates the SSL handshake (no request will arrive to be processed by your application).
2. The client has explicitly opted to trust this certificate, or it opted to ignore expired certs and other errors (`curl -k`). In this case, an https connection is established and the request will proceed. Your app will of course see "https" returned by getScheme() because an https connection *was* established. From the point of view of the client though, it may not be a trustworthy connection.

Comment: You are right, largely this question stemmed from my incomplete comprehension of how an https connection is established. To be even more specific, I don't completely understand under what circumstances a https connection may fail to be established. You have answered my question though. I'll continue reading on the matter. Thanks for the information, hope you get some up votes.